# Python - AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.6, mysql-connector

I am newbie in case of python, i am using python 3.6 and mysql connecter from mysql website

```
pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python
```

Everything was going good. I tried 3 examples from mysql website
Create DB and table , insert, select.

But after 2nd example it stops working and giving a error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "select.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "C:\Users\preet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "C:\Users\preet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
mysql\connector\connection.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .network import MySQLUnixSocket, MySQLTCPSocket
  File "C:\Users\preet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
mysql\connector\network.py", line 28, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\Users\preet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", li
ne 52, in <module>
    import os, sys, io, selectors
  File "C:\Users\preet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\selectors.py",
 line 11, in <module>
    import select
  File "C:\Users\preet\Desktop\ptyhon-newspaper\select.py", line 7, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='Jinqm21k',
AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'
```

Example code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector



cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='****',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='worpress')
cursor = cnx.cursor()                             

query = ("SELECT first_name, last_name, hire_date FROM employees "
         "WHERE hire_date BETWEEN %s AND %s")

hire_start = datetime.date(1999, 1, 1)
hire_end = datetime.date(1999, 12, 31)

cursor.execute(query, (hire_start, hire_end))

for (first_name, last_name, hire_date) in cursor:
  print("{}, {} was hired on {:%d %b %Y}".format(
    last_name, first_name, hire_date))


cursor.close()  
cnx.close()
```

All examples stops working including create, insert, select

I unable to figure out what is wrong with it

Comment: Name your script something other than `select.py`.  You're conflicting with a library module name.

Comment: @john not working after changing name, no luck

Comment: Do you still have `select.pyc`?  If so, remove it.

Comment: @JohnGordon , it start working itself, i don't know how, may be a problem in the system

Answer (score 2):

Your issue was that mysql library was trying to import some packages which imports "select" package which was shadowed by your module "select.py". Please give an updated traceback what is not working now after renaming "select.py".

I also recommend you **not** to write code in the .py file itself, unless you want this code to be executed on module import. Create a routine instead and call it at `__main__` section.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector

def print_employees():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='Jinqm21k',
                              host='localhost',
                              database='worpress')
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    ...

if __name__ = '__main__':
    print_employees()
```

Comment: same trackback regardless of file name, same with test.py

Comment: Could you please provide new traceback?